# nodejs ws library -- how to prevent brute force attack (both for passwords and for crashing)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, brute-force, ws

I'm trying to make an application with NodeJS which heavily depends on users connecting to it via the typcial WebSocket protocol from their browsers, I'm using the ws library for this in nodeJS.

The actual application works fine, and I'm able to disconnect any user (if I can detect that the current IP address has already connected), and authorize it with a user name and password (all taken care of on the server side, after they send the username and password via the websocket, and I can even make a timer on the server side to prevent the client from brute forcing the server to try to authorize itself with a username and password); however, I have not yet found a way to block the connections from happening in the **first** place.

What to I mean? For example, someone, on the client side, can open up their javascript console and simply type something like:

```
setInterval(function() {
    new WebSocket("ws://myServerURL")
}, 1)
```

and simply let that keep going, and pretty soon the entire server will be completely blocked off and / or crashed from the mass amount of constant connections from the same client.

So, although I am able to *disconnect* a user once it's attempted to connect (if I detect that it has already connected on the same IP address, for example), but how can I stop someone from simply sending in constant connections and / or commands like the above code? How can I completely block an entire IP address from opening any new connections, from the outset?

Comment: Unless your server has a very slow connection and / or is extremely slow in handling requests, a single client isn't going to be able to make it "hang" with continues connect / disconnect requests. This is a form of a DoS / DDoS attack which (normally) requires a large botnet for it to have any effect. Like some answers already said: You should catch this long before it reaches your application. You could probably even catch it before it reaches your server using a router with build in firewall or online services like Cloudflare.

Comment: That being said: What you could (and perhaps even should) do on the application level is an auto block / ban on x amount of failed login attempts. Like 5 or 10 x failed attempts: Block for 1 hour. More failed attempts after that? Block for a day. It's quite simple and straight forward to script a feature like that. It'll both help against brute force attacks and stopping unnessesary processing on your server.

Comment: @icecub I realize that is the best thing to doo, but my question is simply **how** can  I block the connections to actually connect in the first place? I can disconnect them once they connect even instantly, but how do I stop the webscoket connections from opening in the first place using the nodejs ws library>

Answer (score 3):

There are npm packages to help with rate-limiting, but I prefer to keep this out of the app server completely as they will still consume resources.

In practice I use [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) as proxies to our api and configure these to [rate-limit](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/) requests.

The following example will limit 10 requests per second based on user's ip:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=10r/s;
```

Nginx is easy to get up and running, battle-tested and well documented.

If using Heroku, you can configure this pretty easily using a buildpack. Here is a [demo repo](https://github.com/samuelgoldenbaum/heroku-ngnix-nodejs) to look at.

Comment: How can I do this from within nodejs using simple the ws library?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this at your application if you must, but I'd recommend putting your server behind Nginx (or similar) and letting Nginx handle preventing these sorts of generic attacks.

https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-ddos-attacks-with-nginx-and-nginx-plus/

That way, you can focus on building your application without having to reinvent the whole thing.

Comment: How would  I be able to do this frmo within nodejs?